# Find and replace in multiple files and add incrementing number

Tags: python, regex, replace

I'm trying to replace a regex pattern in many `.cpp` files on my computer. I need to add an incrementing number at the end of each substitution, so I chose python to do this.

This is what I got already, but it doesn't work yet:

```
import os
import re
i = 0
for file in os.listdir("C:\SeparatorTest"):
    if file.endswith(".cpp"):
        for line in open(file):
            line = re.sub(r'([^\s]*)\.Separator\((.*)\)\;', r'Separator \1\_' + i += 1 + '(\1,\2);')
```

Have I missed something?

Comment: Please define "Doesn't work".

Comment: I run the script, but the files don't change at all. The regex is correct, it works in Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested because I didn't think of what you are trying to replace, but you shouldn't increment like that in the middle of your re.sub call, you need to replace your last line of code with this :

```
line = re.sub(r'([^\s]*)\.Separator\((.*)\)\;', r'Separator \1\_' + i + '(\1,\2);')
i += 1
```

In C++ you'd just put i++ or ++i and the expression would be evaluated to i before or after incrementation, but here I wouldn't try fancy things, python needs to be readable and the next programmer reading your code might not guess what you did. and there is no ++ operator in python.

Edit : And you are just reading your file, the open(file) has default "r", which means reading, and you aren't writing anything. you need open(file, "w") for that. and not just store the re.sub() return value in a variable, but write it to the file.

Edit2 : Here is what I'm working on, it's not done yet, I'll edit as I find how to get it to work :

```
import os, re
i = 0
def replacement(i):
    i += 1
    return r'Separator \1\_' + str(i) + '(\1,\2);'

for file in os.listdir("."):
    if file.endswith(".cpp"):
        for line in open(file):
            re.sub(r'([^\s]*)\.Separator\((.*)\)\;', replacement(i), line)
```

The idea is that the replacement text can be the result of a function that should only be called when a non overlapping pattern matches, according to [The python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

Edit3 : I think I'll stop there, unless I get a response from you because I have some regex and other problems I don't have time to address. Also I'm unsure on best practice for text replacement, you should look for that, there should be help available. Glue the whole thing together (Incrementation, correcting your re.sub() call, open in writing mode, replace the text that matches) and you should achieve what you were trying to do.

Comment: OK, I'll give this a try, but then it increments each line, even if there's no match..

Comment: I'm on python 2.7, which python version are your running ? If this is some new thing I didn't know about, you need to add the python version in the tags, only put the generic "python" if you don't use version-specific stuff. Your code doesn't run on my interpreter.

Can you give examples of matchable strings ? I'm not familiar with regexes, but I've already used re.sub and I'll look for a way to do that, maybe with re.search or re.match.

Comment: I'm on python 3.4, a matchaable string is `AnyString.Separator(AnyString);`

Comment: I'm on it again, but for now re.sub only calls my function once, I need to use something else to count the replacements and increment.

Comment: Maybe I could try using re.find or re.findall, but re.sub seems to be the one I need

Comment: I still don't have a solution for this. A file with the name of the first matching file is created in the same folder as the .py-script is located

Comment: I suggest creating a new file with the replacements first, to avoid losing your files. I find it easier than reading and writing at the same time, and erasing text.